# Infer function signature from an object and a list of keys

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I have a set of indicators represented as an object:

```
type Indicators = {
  UNIT_PRICE: number;
  QUANTITY: number;
  CURRENCY: "$" | "€";
  TOTAL: string;
};
```

I want to describe a computation to be made on this set of indicators:

```
type Computation<R extends { [key: string]: any }> = {
  output: keyof R;
  inputs: Array<keyof R>;
  // I Would like the arguments and the returned value to be type checked
  compute: (...inputs: any[]) => any;
};
```

I did not manage to express the relation between `inputs` (the indicator names) and the arguments of the `compute` function. And the same for `output` and the return type of `compute`. I guess at some point I have to used mapped types, but I did not find out how.

What I would like is to be able to write that kind of code, with typescript complaining if `compute`s signature does not match the types inferred from `inputs` and `output`.

```js
const computation: Computation<Indicators> = {
  output: "TOTAL",
  inputs: ["UNIT_PRICE", "QUANTITY", "CURRENCY"],
  compute: (unitPrice, quantity, currency) =>
    (unitPrice * quantity).toFixed(2) + currency.toUpperCase(),
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgEwJYGMCGwD2AnAzlAXigG8AoKKAVQDkYAVAfQAUAlGAYQFEAuKOAVwC2AIwjYA3OSgBFSgEFqdegE1eAkWMkV2lFi07V2qqACIAJCagAfU4BqCE1qh0A8nTkAZXrmDYkcAOaSAL6SpKCQUOyYgmD8wBhImHAAPCxQEAAewBCI+MRQANoA1hAgXj5+-gC6vGhwIFBBAHyEJFKYcbHAvCUgmABmUCyOfl24vHLY2Gggyb0DQ02OAPTLsFAA6h0ANghQ20glUMAAFtBo2P5COcD4dXun0NgQwPzYcBB7AG5o2-zQWCgoigfn6Ymee362GiUAABqM4rhYVB7nCOsAxrCpChol0ILwABQAOhJCNutXqBSqAEpCC06iBgqEcXBvFAfgcEFEYnEEkleNyunyUvBkOgsHgWkQyBR0V1eCYXG53CYADRSMnjQomGj0ZhsLhq0yyBRKOjKI0mHR6AxGExVdUUHE87KE-hwJDAJi+FAQVVQACO-DqwE9IH9KDezzgKBAtIITSkFAJ7s93tQ0AAVIHg3BQ6BqUSsAAxJAZT4EgBMtIA1FBI1McrGi5hKGBINh2GhcBACdT1SFSKQWWyAO7QgKC3mh-mRXHTxIixCoDA4XBStqyzpxBVKjxqjVwMa8Ao62iMVgcTj2x1QVbrUc7PYHI7hCC4FC+MDAY6Yeu47Y0D8KAzmeIEIHQfgexBH9QXBT5jhODA4VTL0fQgZFR27FE4XUURsCxJ151dKAUw9NCM3jFpUPTX0WzbDsux7PtSEHUh7wANTEBp+guKAoRhUckJ-GA+AgT5-WEOJEOgUQ2VEnF+F2KAED-Akkm2BokmgMl-TgP85TiakhzfKAAGUkBibYICneIZxSOgNxlQoAGkQTgKB5kGOgak3Ch3PlKAXMcIiXXxUiMl4OgChcmk6XZTAkAQRxByCYpSgWHzQmsn8tQsqybOI4VklFFcJXXVpnLJBUTUUFQD1CvFCSDEMwyonNWtAej2zEJje37VjJCAA)

Comment: Do you need `output` and `inputs` as actual properties? If you specify them as type parameters to `Computation`, the solution is fairly straightforward. Otherwise it becomes tricky as you'll want to infer some type parameters but explicitly specify `Indicators`.

Comment: Typescript can't infer the order of the keys in `Indicators`. So at best, you're inputs will be `Array<number | "$" | "€">`, not the tuple `[number, number, "$" | "€"]`. You'd still have to typeguard/assert the inputs within the compute function. Does your `Indicators` type actually correspond to a runtime object, or is it just what you've worked up so far?

Comment: @Oblosys I do need them to be actual properties. The use case is `const updatedData = applyComputation(computation, currentData)`, with `applyComputation` calling `compute` with values extracted from `data` based on what is listed in `inputs`.

Comment: @chrisbajorin the `Indicators` type corresponds to a runtime object: I receive a list of formulae represented as strings describing how indicators relate one to another and I build the `Computation` at runtime based on these formulae.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this to work you need `Computation` to be generic not just in the object type, but also in the [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of input keys and the output key. (Well, technically you could try to reprepresent "every possible tuple of input keys and output key" as a big [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), but this is annoying to represent and does not scale well, so I'm ignoring this possibility.)  For example:

```
type Computation<T extends Record<keyof T, any>,
  IK extends (keyof T)[], OK extends keyof T> = {
    output: OK;
    inputs: readonly [...IK];
    compute: (...inputs: {
      [I in keyof IK]: T[Extract<IK[I], keyof T>]
    }) => T[OK];
  };
```

The object type is `T` (I changed it from `R`), the input keys are `IK` and the output key is `OK`.  The `compute()` method's input parameter list [maps the tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) of keys to a tuple of value types.

---

Now, though, in order to annotate the type of any value, it will be verbose and redundant:

```
const validComputation: Computation<
  Indicators,
  ["UNIT_PRICE", "QUANTITY", "CURRENCY"],
  "TOTAL"
> = {
  output: "TOTAL",
  inputs: ["UNIT_PRICE", "QUANTITY", "CURRENCY"],
  compute: (unitPrice, quantity, currency) =>
    (unitPrice * quantity).toFixed(2) + currency.toUpperCase(),
};
```

Ideally you'd like the compiler to *infer* `IK` and `OK` for you, while letting you specify `T`.  But currently TypeScript does not allow you to partially specify a type; you either have to specify the whole thing, as above, or let the compiler infer the whole type for you.  You could make a helper function to get the compiler to infer `IK` and `OK` for you, but again, any particular call will only infer all of  `T`, `IK`, and `OK`, or none of them.  This whole "partial inference" thing is an open issue in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) for discussion.

The best we can do with the current language is to write something like a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) generic function, where you specify `T` on the initial function and then let the compiler infer `IK` and `OK` on calls to the returned function:

```
const asComputation = <T,>() =>
  <IK extends (keyof T)[], OK extends keyof T>(c: Computation<T, IK, OK>) => c;
```

And it works like this:

```
const asIndicatorsComputation = asComputation<Indicators>();
    
const validComputation = asIndicatorsComputation({
  output: "TOTAL",
  inputs: ["UNIT_PRICE", "QUANTITY", "CURRENCY"],
  compute: (unitPrice, quantity, currency) =>
    (unitPrice * quantity).toFixed(2) + currency.toUpperCase(),
});

const wrongComputation = asIndicatorsComputation({
  output: "TOTAL",
  inputs: ["UNIT_PRICE"],
  compute: (unitPrice) => unitPrice.toUpperCase() // error!
});
```

You call `asComputation<Indicators>()` to get a new helper function which accepts a `Computation<Indicators, IK, OK>` value for some `IK` and `OK` inferred by the compiler.  You can see that you get the desired behavior where the `compute()` method parameters are contextually typed and you'll get an error if you do something wrong.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-DgSGATF8KAgdQAjvwGkzQHUUPxsMc4CgQNiCE0pBRY-HE8noAAqKAZrMJks3LAAMSQGQgCF6ACZsQBqKB5gs5YttzCUMCQbDsNC4CC9YbiokkpLkhc8uJ8uCrVI1JrLnFSBEzLrzfogoZjFHTTpzHqopZ0I8obnRXlM-l0VptKZtE0pYrCgoSkpuuBCqgGA4Lg26Msyqxbp+O7fikUEirBR7DKE65ksAlLUrS8G7khkGINBopwShCFJL0lpQNatqmEajrihQLpulKtCenKPqKsqAZqkGughrq4YjjR0ZVgmSaoKmjaZnA2YgLm+aFsWwEVjGcaybWUANk2yktsMk6dt2vYDlAw6jhpICTtOs7zouy6rjhxLgQRADu2BJP4JFoWRGEwXgAXMvR6ybHEdqsSa7GAnABy8O6PGyt6erxZGrzvLpNbycBUC5XJKYOTOYjOUu2IAPRVekBY4AAhIS7mkEAA)

Comment: The `readonly [...IK]` is an interesting trick, I've been extending a type `Tuple<T> = [] | [T, ...T[]]` to work around `readonly` failures on array type parameters, but this is easier.

Comment: Yeah, if you look at the [pull request for variadic tuples](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094), it says "The type `[...T]`, where `T` is an array-like type parameter, can conveniently be used to indicate a preference for inference of tuple types".  It definitely makes things easier.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was provided on gitter by someone named @webstrand.

First, mapped types make it possible to express the relation between `output`, `inputs` and the `compute` signature:

```
type Computation<
  R extends { [key: string]: any },
  // readonly is important to make typescript infer tuples instead of arrays later on
  I extends readonly (keyof R)[],
  O extends keyof R,
> = {
  output: O;
  inputs: I;
  compute: (...inputs: { [P in keyof I]: I[P] extends keyof R ? R[I[P]] : never }) => R[O];
};
```

This version requires the user to be explicit about the types.

Then comes the "double call" hack because typescript only infers types at the function call site:

```
function createComputation<R extends { [key: string]: any }>(): <I extends readonly (keyof R)[], O extends keyof R>(o: Computation<R, I, O>) => Computation<R, I, O> {
  return (x) => x;
}
```

And now, we can use `createComputation` to type check everything:

```
const validComputation = createComputation<Indicators>()({
  output: "TOTAL",
  inputs: ["UNIT_PRICE", "QUANTITY", "CURRENCY"] as const,
  compute: (unitPrice, quantity, currency) =>
    (unitPrice * quantity).toFixed(2) + currency.toUpperCase(),
});
```